# SSIS Data Conversion The data value cannot be converted for reasons other than sign mismatch or data overflow

Tags: string, ssis, etl, data-conversion, unicode-string

Does anyone know why I'm getting error below when converting string [DT_STR] to Unicode string [DT_WSTR] in SSIS Data Conversion?

> ErrorCode: -1071607681
>
> ErrorCode - Description: The data value cannot be converted for reasons other than sign mismatch or data overflow.

Comment: Redirect the error flow to some destination and put a data viewer on that path to see which value can't be converted.

Comment: check the destination column length

Comment: Because sometimes SSIS error messages are poorly worded.   What is the data that produces the error?

Comment: Are lengths of both column equal?

Answer (score 0):

In my case the Excel (source) file column contained text, and the Excel formatting was set to a custom date format.  The content of the column was text, set the formatting to text and the error was resolved.